# Is this construction <go someone something that clause> grammatically permissible?

Tags: verbs, construction

> I'll go you three dollars that the horse is going to win the race.

I made this sentence myself.
My gut is telling me there's no problem in grammar and in this case "go" can be meant for "bet" or "wager". 
If my sentence doesn't sound natural or isn't grammatically correct, could you tell me the reason why?

Answer (score 2):

As someone from the west coast of the USA, it doesn't sound right to me. I've never heard 'go' used that way, but this could be perfectly fine in other places. 'Bet' is what I'd use here.

However, the phase *(do) you wanna go?* is a kind of slang for a challenge; a bet that 'you' can't defeat 'me' in whatever activity matches the context. This might be what you were thinking of, but this is the only case where it makes any kind of sense.

Comment: You're saying my sentence doesn't make any sense?, or even though it does make sense, it just doesn't sound right, because you've never heard "go" used in that way?

Comment: @Floret It doesn't make sense for my dialect, which is pretty plain. A person shouldn't be an object of 'go'.

Comment: In that case, "you" is used as an indirect object.

Comment: Still, "you" as any object for "go" doesn't really make sense, unless someone is "going to you". In that case, it's separated by a conjunction though; it's not an indirect or direct object. ("To" is in the sense of direction.)

Comment: Then, what about this sentence without "you"? **"I'll go three dollars that the horse is going to win the race"**.  Does this sentence make no sense as well?

Comment: Yeah, it's not right.

Comment: Hmm... it's so interesting for someone an usage of a verb that is registered even in a dictionary cannot make sense

Comment: Oh, what does it say? Or do you have a link of some kind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94096/discussion-between-floret-and-cranberry48).